# FileOption.RandomAccess ,what is the effect of adding it to the FileStream constructor?

Tags: c#, filestream

i read about FileOption enum and i saw this value RandomAccess

i read that it optimize File caching , i want to know how it do this

and what will happen if i put it or not ?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("hello.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.ReadWrite,4096,FileOptions.RandomAccess);
```

and i think (RandomAccess,SequentialScan,WriteThrough) values, They have to do with each other

Can any one explain them to me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: `RandomAccess` maps to `FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS` and `SequentialScan` maps to `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` in the windows API `CreateFile()`. See [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120120-00/?p=849) for more information about what effect that has.

Comment: "oops Page not found , that page cannot be found" . are there any another link ?

Comment: Oops - corrected link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120120-00/?p=8493 Also note that article is about Windows 7 - Windows 10 might be different (but it should give you the general idea!)

Comment: okay i understand some things in this article but there are other things i cant understand it , i think because i dont know a lot about CreateFile native Method can you send me link explain it to me please ?

Comment: Well the documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea but you probably need to know a bit about Windows API calls to really understand it.

Comment: It would probably be a far better use of your time to wait until you have a *problem* for which someone suggests one of these options as a *solution*. You'll then have a concrete example in front of you from which you can understand the usage.

Comment: You have to understand how the file system cache works to make sense of these options.  For a spindle disk, the OS doesn't just read the file data you asked for, it reads an entire track of data.  Since that's (almost) as cheap as reading a sector.  With the benefit that it won't have to access the disk on the next Read() call.  With FileOptions.SequentialAccess it reads more, with RandomAccess it reads less.  That saves RAM.  Mattered back in the early 1990s when the OS had to run in 16MB of RAM.  Today, the effort of measuring whether you're actually ahead isn't worth it anymore.